# How to listen to CollectionChanged event and execute some method

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, inotifycollectionchanged

My viewmodel has two Collections, one is `MainCollection` and other is `DerivedCollection`. They are displayed using a control, so that when user interacts with the mouse, items can be added or removed from `MainCollection`, and `DerivedCollection` should be refreshed accordingly.

The first part (updating `MainCollection`) happens automatically via data-binding, but I don' know how can I hook `RefreshDerivedCollection` method to `MainCollection.PropertyChanged` event.

Both collections and the method live in the same viewmodel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscribe to [`MainCollection.CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.live.messenger.collection.collectionchanged.aspx) and [refresh](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/wpf-tip-collection-changed-event/) derived collection there:

```
MainCollection.CollectionChanged += this.OnMainCollectionChanged;
```

and

```
void OnMainCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Handle main collection change here.
}
```

Comment: Well, that's what I tried to do, but missed the `CollectionChanged` event among so many other properties in intellisense... :P  Thanks!